# Cannot get values from span class

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to read a value of price from a website using Excel VBA but I get an Error

> Object does not support this property or method

The part of HTML

```html
<div class="box-three box-right col-xs-20 col-lg-5 col-md-6 no-gutter">
<div class="inner-box-one">
<div class="price-container" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
<span class="price-label">Τιμή:</span>
<span class="final-price"><span itemprop="price">594,00 €</span> </span>
<meta itemprop="currency" content="EUR" />
<meta itemprop="availability" content="in_stock" />
</div>
```

I am trying with this:

```
Dim getPrice As Object
Set getPrice = ie.Doc.getElementByClassName("final-price")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.innerText
wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = myValue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many of these are there on the page and is it the first? Your error is because you are trying to use a method for a single element on a collection as you haven't used an index on the collection to retrieve a single item.

You can return a nodeList of all matching classes with

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".final-price")
```

Then access each by index:

```
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length-1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText
Next
```

The "." is a [class css selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). It targets the elements by their class name.  The space between two class selectors represents a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), stating that the second class must be a child of the first class.

```
.price-container .price-label
```

You may wish to grab labels and prices together:

```
Dim labels As Object, prices As Object, i As Long
Set labels = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".price-container .price-label")
Set prices = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".price-container .final-price")

For i = 0 To labels.Length - 1
    Debug.Print labels.item(i).innerText & " " & prices.item(i).innerText
Next
```

Which, in fact, you could further combine as:

```
Dim labelsPrices, i As Long
Set labelsPrices = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".price-container .price-label, .price-container .final-price")

For i = 0 To labels.Length - 1 Step 2
    Debug.Print labels.item(i).innerText & " " & prices.item(i + 1).innerText
Next
```

CSS selectors are applied via [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) methods - in this case, of `.document`. The first returns a single element i.e. the first match, the second returns all matches.

---

Single item:

You can use the last bit of code directly above to get label and price as there would be two elements if a single price and single label.

Or

```
Dim label As Object, price As Object, i As Long
Set label= ie.document.querySelector(".price-container .price-label")
Set price = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".price-container .final-price")

Debug.Print label.innerText, price.innerText
```

Comment: It is a single product page with one price, So I need nevertheless the nodelist?

Comment: how to display it to a cell? Debug.Print it will display it on selected cell?

Comment: Cells(1,1) = price.innerText.   Etc

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim getPrice As Object
Set getPrice = ie.Doc.getElementByClassName("final-price")(0) 'While Using Class Name you must indicate an index of that class
Dim myValue As String: myValue = getPrice.innerText
wks.Cells(i, "C").Value = myValue
```

Comment: And What is ie.doc? it should be 
    ie.Document.getelementsbyClassName

Comment: Then use the [edit] link and include that information **in** your Answer, not as a comment below it. And don't use a question mark in an Answer - that would be a comment *below the question*. State it more like: `ie.doc` doesn't compile - it should be... and use the correct syntax in the code you provide. Especially since this is more likely the cause of the error message.